# What is the word for a pair of bytes?

Tags: terminology, computing

*Bit* is a portmanteau of *binary digit*.

A *byte* is 8 bits.

A *nibble* is 4 bits (half a byte).

Is there a word for a pair of bytes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is `word` which is 16 bits.

They are (in order of increasing size)

```
BIT, NIBBLE, BYTE, WORD, DWORD, FWORD, QWORD, KiloByte, MegaByte
```

Please note that a `word` is the standard memory bus width in your architecture. It can be 8 bits or 16 bits or 32 bits or 64 bits based on the CPU.

You can read more about assembler(binary) [here](http://101.lv/learn/asm/asmintro.html) (this is a random link I found on google for your reference, but I verified that the information is correct about the above mentioned. Search on google).

Comment: If *word* is so flexible, how can it definitively mean "a pair of bytes" if *byte* means only eight bits?

Comment: Unless otherwise excited, it decays to the ground state.

Comment: @Robusto: A `word` is 16 bits in a conventional sense. As a matter of fact, the most common architecture even in the present day is x86-32, in which a `word` is 16 bits. Like @coleopterist mentioned in his comment, more details can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr A word is 32 bits on x86-32 and 64 bits on x86-64.  Some x86-specific technical documents use "word" to mean a 16-bit value for consistency with documentation and software written for 8086 processors, which had 16-bit words.  This usage of "word" does not mean that x86 processors use 16-bit words.  See the list of word sizes at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Answer (score 1):

I will offer this up as a suggestion, though I don't believe it was ever used in *serious* writing. A *playte* is unambiguously 16 bits, and also; *chawmp* in the context of a 32 bit machine.

see [here](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nybble.html) and [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/playte)

I would've just commented on the previous answer but I don't have enough reputation yet, so I'll leave an alternate answer instead.

Also, I believe *nybble* is the correct spelling for four bits.